# How to clear a text box in uipath?

Tags: rpa, uipath

I am creating RPA. Text box have some default value. I want to enter my value after clearing that default value. How can i do it?
I tried `[k(back)]` this one but it is clear only one char at a time. I am unable to find default value length so that I will run this `[k(back)]` activity in for loop.

Answer (score 8):

Use the activity **Type Into** and in the properties check **EmptyField**.

[image]

This property empties the field before writing the text specified in the property **Text**.

Alternatively, if you need to empty a field you can write " " in the property **Text**.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, for example in sitecore, where we have multiple lines, checking Empty Field property clears only first line. So alternately, what we have done is send hotkey activity 'Ctrl+A' which selects entire text and then write the required text value into it.